# Java: Create and put new file inside deployed webapplication on run time

Tags: java, spring-mvc, file-upload, file-io

I want to create and put new file inside deployed webapplication on run time.
Normal file handling using java.io package is not working.

EDITED:

Actually when I look my web application home page then required styles are not applying to concerned content.

Below is the line which I used to include css for required page style:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="<%=request.getContextPath()%>/mystyle.css" />
```

Problem is, its not getting css file.

So for available of that file I wrote some backend code in spring controller class for writing file at required location like below:

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping("/dest")
public class MyController {
.
.
.
try{
String file = "C:/Users/Shobhit.Singh/Documents/NetBeansProjects/target/mywebapplication/mystyle.css";
//this is location i am getting on UI side by <%=request.getRealPath("/")%>/mystyle.css            
FileWriter fstream = new FileWriter("C:/Users/Shobhit.Singh/Documents/NetBeansProjects/target/mywebapplication/mystyle.css");

          BufferedWriter out = new BufferedWriter(fstream);
          out.write(styles.toString());
          out.close();
          System.out.println("*********DONE******************");
         }catch (Exception e){
          System.err.println("Error: " + e.getMessage());
         }

}
```

Either file is written in location as in java code but not getting availability on location as required in UI as below:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="<%=request.getContextPath()%>/mystyle.css" />
```

Can anybody please point me where I am doing wrong and what may be the solution?
I have to avail css file on run time.

Let me please know if further clarification is needed!

Comment: What are you trying to achieve? Packaged wars are usually 'exploded' by the container into a temporary/work folder, so you will have to play with the URLClassLoader. If it is just to make the resource 'available', there are simpler ways.

Comment: @Lucifer Yes, Now I posted my code.

Answer (score 0):

I have done with my posted approach. Mistake I was doing was, location on which I have to write file, location using in java code should be as below:

```
FileWriter fstream = new FileWriter("C:/Users/Shobhit.Singh/Documents/NetBeansProjects/target/mywebapplication/styles/mystyle.css");
```

Well, thanks to read and suggest on my posted problem. If anybody has better solution, please let me know.

Regards